# declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

Tags: support

I flagged this answer up by user "Cthulhubutt",

[Error while creating site from specific template](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96837/error-while-creating-site-from-specific-template)

But it was declined because of,

> declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of
>   content that requires their intervention

But later on answer has been converted into comment.

**Question**
- So are we not supposed to flag answers that are not actually answers but comments :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should!

The reason in this case behind it first being declined and the converted is probably as easy as one moderator did review your flag and declined it, while another spotted the question and converted the "answer" to a comment (not connected to the actual flag)